# Does AnyEvent work with perl 5.26?

Tags: perl, anyevent

I've met the following error::

`Can't use an undefined value as a subroutine reference at /home/basiliscos/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.26.0/lib/site_perl/5.26.0/x86_64-linux/AnyEvent/Loop.pm line 248`

when I run my program under perl 5.26.0, meanwhile under 5.20.3 it runs fine.

Any ideas where I should dig to?

Comment: The first place to dig would be your code, right?  Any chance that we can see some trimmed down version that demonstrates the problem?  The fact that "_it runs fine_" on a previous version still doesn't have to mean that the library is to blame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, the issue seems in the `EV` dependency; it **should** be optional, but installing it solves the problem. I hope it will be useful for somebody.